# UICollectionView sporadically crashes when NSTimer triggers reloadData and bouncing is enabled in iOS 7 on iPad

Tags: crash, ios7, uicollectionview, nstimer, bounce

Am I doing something wrong or there is a problem with the system?

Very simple demo: https://github.com/IgorTavcar/UICollectionViewBug.

Here is a collection view and a periodic trigger, started by

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
}
```

Every `tick` invokes the `roladData` of collection view.

```
- (void)tick {
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}
```

If scroll view

```
@property(nonatomic) BOOL bounces
```

is TRUE

then application **crashes** with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after max. 15 seconds of intensive scrolling /bouncing/.

Any suggestions?

I've also tried to do the

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
});
```

and

```
self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:TRUE];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

...

Comment: Please enable NSZombies and see if a specific instance has been released. Could be an Apple bug, in which case you should open a bug report (despite any workaround you may find).

Comment: NSZombies spotted: `*** -[NSIndexPath section]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17d8c3a0`  deep inside `-[UICollectionView _unhighlightAllItems]`

Comment: Likely an Apple bug due to some race condition. Open bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com and add a sample project for them to see, as well as the `bt` and the "deallocated instance" message.

Comment: Bug reported to Apple: ticket-id 15095954

Comment: If you are lucky, they will fix it in iOS8.0 :) I still have serious bugs open from the early days of iOS7 betas.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? I have the same problem..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

https://github.com/IgorTavcar/UICollectionViewBug/issues/1

Uncheck "User Interaction Enabled" and "Multiple Touch" from the Collection View Cell in the Story Board.

Use a gesture recognizer to handle it input instead.

Comment: If user interaction is disabled, then how will a gesture recogniser work?